# Read XML dynamic PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

in my site in PHP I want to read an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<RETURNDATA lang="it-IT" type="COR" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlv5test.travco.co.uk/trlink/schema/CountryRequestV6Rcv.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MESSAGE>All Countries details and relevant city details</MESSAGE>
    <DATA COUNTRY_CODE="ABW" CURRENCY_CODE="EUR">
        <COUNTRY_NAME>Aruba</COUNTRY_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_NAME>euro</CURRENCY_NAME>
        <COUNTRY_CITIES>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="AUA">
                <CITY_NAME>Aruba</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
        </COUNTRY_CITIES>
    </DATA>
    <DATA COUNTRY_CODE="ALB" CURRENCY_CODE="EUR">
        <COUNTRY_NAME>Albania</COUNTRY_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_NAME>euro</CURRENCY_NAME>
        <COUNTRY_CITIES>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="TIA">
                <CITY_NAME>Tirana</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
        </COUNTRY_CITIES>
    </DATA>
    <DATA COUNTRY_CODE="ARE" CURRENCY_CODE="EUR">
        <COUNTRY_NAME>Emirati Arabi Uniti</COUNTRY_NAME>
        <CURRENCY_NAME>euro</CURRENCY_NAME>
        <COUNTRY_CITIES>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="DXB">
                <CITY_NAME>Dubai</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="AAI">
                <CITY_NAME>Al Ain</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="FJR">
                <CITY_NAME>Fujaira</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="SSH">
                <CITY_NAME>Sharja</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="RKT">
                <CITY_NAME>Ras al-Khaimah</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
            <CITY_DATA CITY_CODE="AUH">
                <CITY_NAME>Abu Dhabi</CITY_NAME>
            </CITY_DATA>
         </COUNTRY_CITIES>
     </DATA>
</RETURNDATA>
```

I want to enter in each  node name DATA and take:
COUNTRY_CODE
CURRENCY_CODE
COUNTRY_NAME
CURRENCY_NAME
And all ountry cities code and name into an array associative.

I have tried with SimpleXML, but the XML is dynamic and I wanto to optimize my cycle because I can have a very big and large XML (this is only a little part of It).

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents('xml/country.xml');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
    echo $xml->getName(), PHP_EOL;
    foreach($xml as $name => $part) {
       echo "$name: $part", PHP_EOL;
    }
```

I want to create a very otpimize cycle to take my  value

Comment: What does not work with your code? I mean what is the concrete issue? SimpleXML normally just works but you don't write where it does not work specifically for you. You should probably say in your question so it can be answered ;)

Comment: I want to retrieve my data in the most efficient mode @hakre

Comment: define "efficient mode". That can mean a lot. Why do you say for example it's not efficient right now?

Comment: Efficient mode because i have to search inside a node pther node with other foreach i have attribute and node i have some things to retrieve and some foreach to create for this reason i want an efficient mode in term of speed because i have a very big xml @hakre

Comment: if you answer at my question with your code I accept it because I have solved with your comment @hakre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following style to acces only the `<DATA>` child elements in the root element:

```
foreach ($xml->DATA as $name => $part) {
```

Also please check the [SimpleXML Introduction](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic.php) it should have some good examples for you showing different ways how to do the basic stuff with SimpleXML. The documentation is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the XML parser directly, this would more than likely be the most efficient way

```
set_time_limit(0);
define('__BUFFER_SIZE__', 131072);
define('__XML_FILE__', 'pf_1360591.xml');

function elementStart($p, $n, $a) {
  //handle opening of elements
}

function elementEnd($p, $n) {
  //handle closing of elements
}

function elementData($p, $d) {
  //handle cdata in elements
}

$xml = xml_parser_create();

xml_parser_set_option($xml, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
xml_parser_set_option($xml, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parser_set_option($xml, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);

xml_set_element_handler($xml, 'elementStart', 'elementEnd');
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml, 'elementData');

$f = fopen(__XML_FILE__, 'r');
if($f) {
  while(!feof($f)) {
    $content = fread($f, __BUFFER_SIZE__);

    xml_parse($xml, $content, feof($f));

    unset($content);
  }
  fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Ok but in my case to take my value which is the besto mode to retrieve my information?