# How to iterate through an XML element node with dynamic children

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I currently have the following XML structure:

```
<root>
  <maininfo>
    <node>
      <tournament_id>3100423</tournament_id>
      <games>
        <a_0>
          <id>23523636</id>
          <type>
            <choice_4>
              <choice_id>345</choice_id>
            <choice_4>
            <choice_9>
              <choice_id>345</choice_id>
            <choice_9>
            ... etc
          </type>
        </a_0>
        <a_1></a_1>
        <a_2></a_2>
        ...etc
      </games>
    </info>
  </node>
</root>
```

I can easily get the id of the first node element "a_0" by just doing:

```
maininfo[0]->a_3130432[0]->games[0]->a_1[0]->id;
```

**My issue is:**
How do I automatically iterate (with a foreach) through all `a_0`, `a_1`, `a_2` and get the values of each of these node elements and all of their children like "345" in `<choice_id>345</choice_id>`?

The ending numbers of `a_0`, `a_1` + the children of `choice_4`, `choice_9`, are dynamically created and there are no logic in the _[number] counting up with +1 for each next element.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been outlined previously on Stackoverflow (for example in [*Read XML dynamic PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15273870/367456)) and as well generally in the PHP manual (for example in [*Basic SimpleXML usage*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)), you can iterate over all child elements by using `foreach`.

For example to go over all `a_*` elements, it's just

```
foreach ($xml->maininfo->node->games[0] as $name => $a) {
    echo $name, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a_0
a_1
a_2
```

You then want to iterate over these their `->type` children again. This *is* possible in pure PHP by putting one `foreach` into a another:

```
foreach ($xml->maininfo->node->games[0] as $name => $a) {
    echo $name, "\n";

    if (!$a->type[0]) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($a->type[0] as $name => $choice) {
        echo ' +- ', $name, "\n";
    }
}
```

This now outputs:

```
a_0
 +- choice_4
 +- choice_9
a_1
a_2
```

This starts to get a bit complicated. As you can imagine since XML is famous for it's tree structures, you're not the first one running into this problem. Therefore a query-language to get elements from an XML document has been invented: *Xpath*.

With *Xpath* you can access XML data as if it was a file-system. As I know that each `a_*` element is a child of `games` and each `choice_*` element a child of type, it's pretty straight forward:

```
 /*/maininfo/node/games/*/type/*
  ^                     ^      ^
  |                     |   choice_*
root                    |
                       a_*
```

In PHP Simplexml this looks like:

```
$choices = $xml->xpath('/*/maininfo/node/games/*/type/*');

foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    echo $choice->getName(), ': ', $choice->choice_id, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
choice_4: 345
choice_9: 345
```

As this example shows, the data is now retrieved with a single `foreach`.

If you as well need access to the `<a_*>` elements, you *need* to have multiple `foreach`'s *or* your own iteration but that is even a more advanced topic which I'd say would extend over the limits of your question.

I hope this is helpful so far. See as well [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.children) which also gives all children (like `->games[0]` in the first example). All example codes are as well available as [a working, interactive online-demo](https://eval.in/38366).

Comment: I'm not sure XPath *in general* as "access XML data as if it was a file-system", although I guess a relatively simple expression like this is pretty reminiscent of a file glob. I could probably look this up somewhere, but can XPath evaluate a partial wild-card like `//a_*`?

Comment: @IMSoP: The file-system comparison is an analogy, it's not perfectly the same. partial wild-cards don't work as you outline it, it's with string expressions or - possible in PHP - putting regex matching functions in there.

Comment: OK, thanks. Some day I'll take the time to learn XPath beyond the basics :)

Comment: xpath 1.0 sometimes is a bit akward, but often better to use than X foreaches inside each other, so a good tool in the box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you can do something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $max; ++$i){
    $a = $parentNode->{'a_'.$i};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily using SimpleXML :

```
<?php
$xmlStr = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
  <maininfo>
    <node>
      <tournament_id>3100423</tournament_id>
      <games>
    <a_0>
      <id>23523636</id>
      <type>
        <choice_4>
          <choice_id>345</choice_id>
        </choice_4>
        <choice_9>
          <choice_id>345</choice_id>
        </choice_9>
      </type>
    </a_0>
    <a_1></a_1>
    <a_2></a_2>
      </games>
  </node>
  </maininfo>
</root>";

$xmlRoot = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$i = 0;
foreach($xmlRoot->maininfo[0]->node[0]->games[0] as $a_x)
{
    echo $i++ . " - " . htmlentities($a_x->asXML()) . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

I have modified some parts of your XML string to make it syntactically correct. You can view the results at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/56q-san

Comment: It seems that Will just print it all (including node names)? Or perhaps im just looking at the fiddle wrong. What im looking to do is being able to access/iterate through the values of the different elements by individual $value_vars